# New install google apps not accessible from home screen

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

After install an apps from google marketplaces, it does not appear in the google.com home screen as we expected.
The apps only appears in the apps dashboard when user goes to Gmail, Drive etc.
We want the apps appear in dashboard for every screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but all the apps are in the 9 squares in the upper right corner [image]

There you can find google apps as well as installed apps.